# Creating date sequence between two given dates - fails on february

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Im using the following method to create a date sequence between two given dates;

```
public List<DateTime> dateSeq(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    List<DateTime> allDates = new List<DateTime>();

    for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddMonths(1))
        allDates.Add(date);

    return allDates;
}
```

Creating a date sequence while incrementing 1 month, when the given date for example are:

```
startDate: 2017-01-01 
endDate: 2017-05-01
```

the sequence i get is fine:

```
2017-01-01
2017-02-01
2017-03-01
2017-04-01
2017-05-01
```

But when the given dates are:

```
startDate: 2017-01-31 
endDate: 2017-05-31
```

The sequence i get fail when passing february setting the rest of the months sequence on the 28th day:

```
2017-01-31
2017-02-28
2017-03-28
2017-04-28
2017-05-28
```

Can someone please explain why is that?

Comment: Because the last day in the month of february on a non-leap year is the 28. Adding 1 month to that date will be the 28 of march, and so on. Not sure what is not to understand. If you want to have a function like this use the start of each month, not the end, so you do not have to deal with the number of days in each month which varies across months and years (leap year/non leap year) (28, 29, 30, and 31).

Comment: How is the expected behaviour if startdate is `2017-02-28`?

Answer (score 2):

Because the `2017-02-31` doesn't exist and `2017-02-28.AddMonth(1)` results into `2017-03-28` which is correct.

I think you're looking for a approach which maintains the initial start day

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> dateSeq(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    int temp = 0;
    while (startDate.AddMonths(temp) <= endDate)
        yield return startDate.AddMonths(temp++);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mz7yFh

Comment: That still would not work if the `startDate` was `2017-02-28` and `endDate` was `2017-05-30`. You have to use either dates that ignore the date (ie. start on the 1st of the month) or enrich the logic to set the variable date to the last date of the month being checked.

Comment: @Igor the question is not about the last day of the month - OP also mentioned the `2017-01-01` example